# Want to disable 'call tips' in python 2.7.10

Tags: python

I want to disable the call tips feature in Python's Idle. In 2.7.10, I saw an option to configure the extensions in the 2.7.10 IDLE, which the 2.5 IDLE did not have. I was very excited to see that one of the extensions I could configure was the call tips extension, but when I clicked on it, I didn't know what to do. The result simply said "Enable" next to a box into which I could type a number; the default was 1. I tried typing in 0 and hitting apply, but this did not get rid of call tips. How can I disable call tips?